# How to use fs.createReadStream() in sync without call back

Tags: node.js, fs, vscode-extensions

I am planning to copy a file content from the zip and place the binary contents in another file. which will be used when I require a package.

example:-

```
      func_name(CURRENT_DIR);
      const MainController = require('./src/controllers/mainController');
      // This mainController file will require the binary file which is create the func_name function
      controller = new MainController(
        context,
        db2ConnectOutputChannel,
        undefined /*vscodeWrapper*/
      );
      context.subscriptions.push(controller);
      controller.activate();
```

func_name defination

```
        var odbcBindingsNode;
        var ODBC_BINDINGS = path.resolve(CURRENT_DIR, 'node_modules\/ibm_db\/build\/Release\/odbc_bindings.node');
        odbcBindingsNode = 'build\/Release\/odbc_bindings_e' + electron_version + '.node';
        readStream = fs.createReadStream(BUILD_FILE);
        readStream.pipe(unzipper.Parse())
            .on('entry', function (entry) {
                if(entry.path === odbcBindingsNode) {
                    entry.pipe(fstream.Writer(ODBC_BINDINGS));
                } else {
                    entry.autodrain();
                }
            })
            .on('error', function(e) {
                console.log('Installation Failed! \n',e);
            })
            .on('finish', function() {
              console.log("\n" + 
              "===================================\n"+
              "installed successfully!\n"+
              "===================================\n");
              })
```

The problem is the first function will not wait till the second function completes. It moves to the next line and tries to require maincontroller file which requires this .node file and returns .node is not found.
But .node is created after the require is called. Is there a way to make it in sync?

I tried callback which returns that require cannot be used in callback.

CallBack Code:-

```
function akhil(CURRENT_DIR){
          var BUILD_FILE = path.resolve(CURRENT_DIR, 'folder\/build.zip');
          var odbcBindingsNode;
          var ODBC_BINDINGS = path.resolve(CURRENT_DIR, 'folder\/build\/Release\/odbc_bindings.node');
          odbcBindingsNode = 'build\/Release\/odbc_bindings_e' + electron_version + '.node'
          readStream = fs.createReadStream(BUILD_FILE);
          /*
            * unzipper will parse the build.zip file content and
            * then it will check for the odbcBindingsNode
            * (node Binary), when it gets that binary file,
            * fstream.Writer will write the same node binary
            * but the name will be odbc_bindings.node, and the other
            * binary files and build.zip will be discarded.
            */
            readStream.pipe(unzipper.Parse())
              .on('entry', function (entry) {
                  if(entry.path === odbcBindingsNode) {
                      entry.pipe(fstream.Writer(ODBC_BINDINGS));
                  } else {
                      entry.autodrain();
                  }
              })
              .on('error', function(e) {
                  console.log('Installation Failed! \n',e);
              })
              .on('finish', function() {
                console.log("\n" + 
                "===================================\n"+
                "installed successfully!\n"+
                "===================================\n");
                console.log("This is rebuild");
                const MainController = require('./src/controllers/mainController');
                controller = new MainController(
                  context,
                  db2ConnectOutputChannel,
                  undefined /*vscodeWrapper*/
                );
                context.subscriptions.push(controller);
                controller.activate();
                })
            return 1;
    }
```

Comment: could you post the code and error message of the attempt to use a callback

Comment: there is no error message..when I call require in the callback it stops there. cosole.log() is also not printed after the require.

Comment: you know, it's really hard to diagnose why "it stops there" without seeing the code

Comment: @pspi I have added the callback code..please check in the question section

Comment: this unzipping functionality looks ok, although it's hard to to read, but i'm sure you'll refactor it once you get it working. next thing i'd do is add debug logs to the required mainController file, the problem is likely there. try to pinpoint where it stops processing and starts to hang. it's hanging because based on your description it doesn't return and print the following console.log lines after it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ADM-zip package I was able to solve this issue.